# Limit searches to within specific tags

Tags: support, tags, search

Is there a way to limit my searching to only specific tags?

For example:
If I search for "[tcp networking](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22tcp+networking%22)" I get matches in almost every category.
What I really meant was tcp networking (in [**[android]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android))

I know I could (potentially) add the implied tag to the search but I thought that since this website was so (nicely) tag oriented there must be some way to limit to a set (or just one) tag.

I thought that by clicking a tag that the search would understand that that is the only group I am interested in. But it does not seem that way.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a meta question. You can ask in the http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Thanks for moving this into META, as you can see below I did get very useful responses.

BTW, I didn't even know there was a META... again, also very useful intel.

Thanks.. tob

Answer (score 1):

see search tips!

https://stackoverflow.com/search

short answer, search for

"tcp networking [android]"

without the quotes