# Search for a question inside of tags

Tags: support, search

I want to search for all questions containing "tab control" that are also "tagged" c# how do I do this?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39150/limit-searches-to-specific-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for "[c#] tab control" (no quotes).

There is also [a tag for tab controls specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tabcontrol), which you can filter on that page by C#.

The full search syntax is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search).